# Conditional catalog compilation

Tags: puppet

I have two servers, for example `app01.zone1.mydomain.com` and `app01.zone2.mydomain.com`. I have a class `app` that the node classifier assigns to each host with hostname matching `app*`. The `app` class is something like the following:

```
class app inherits common {
  include 'appm'
}
```

It just includes the `appm` module.

Now, the `appm` module got some code which would break in `zone2`. So, I modified the `app` class to the following.

```
class app inherits common {
  if ($zone == 'zone1'){
     include 'appm'
  }
}
```

However, when the catalog is being compiled, the condition is ignored. Due to that, the compilation fails when the agent on `app01.zone2.mydomain.com` tries to sync.

Is there any way to make catalog compilation honour the condition ? Any other suggestion for the situation ?

Comment: You have your class `app` including *itself* if it gets evaluated at all.  That's surely not what you intended.  I suspect that in fact, that class is not evaluated, but instead your other class `app` is selected and evaluated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see where the confusion is stemming from. Let me make corrections to the question to add more context.

Comment: Where and how does `$zone` get its value?

Comment: Assume $zone is a global variable.

Comment: I am already assuming that `$zone` is in scope, for if it weren't then the condition would never evaluate to tue instead of always evaluating to true.  I asked about *where and how it gets its value*.

Comment: Additionally, you can check simultaneously whether Puppet is using the version of the class you think and whether `$zone` has the value you think by inserting into class App a `Notify` resource whose message contains the value of `$zone`.  Chances are very good that this experiment will clarify the nature of the problem.

Comment: John, I tried the notification approach earlier but you see I am talking about catalog compilation on the master. It is different from applying the manifest on the agent side. I think the notify will work on the agent side.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked that it is catalog building that fails.  In that case, you can use one of Puppet's built-in logging functions, say [`notice()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/function.html#notice), in place of a `Notify`.  That will output the information into the master's log, at catalog-building time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional matching a regular expression for your case:

```
class app inherits common {
  if $::fqdn =~ /^app(\d+)\.zone1\./ {
    include 'appm'
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding a few more lines of explanation or output examples to the answer would be good to understand the solution.

Comment: I was actually trying to imply that zone is another variable like fqdn that is globally available. The condition you have added is no different than the one I have. It does not prevent the catalog compilation to go into the condition.